# How can I fix 'Error 1364: field 'Date' doesn't have a default value' in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1364

Error 1364: field 'Date' doesn't have a default value.

in the following table I've created in my server, as well as most others, i'm running into the  error above when inputting my date values, and I'm unsure how to fix it. the table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`enrollment` (
  `EnrollmentId` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,  
  `Date` DATETIME NOT NULL, 
  `SchoolId` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`EnrollmentId`),
  INDEX `fk_Enrollment_School1_idx` (`SchoolId` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Enrollment_School1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`SchoolId`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`school` (`SchoolId`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

here is the statements for the table:

```
 INSERT INTO enrollment (EnrollmentId) VALUES 
 ('pegsue5687'),
 ('dangia4965'),
 ('leegun3465'), 
 ('harkan5690'), 
 ('donsal8774'); 
 
INSERT INTO enrollment (Date) VALUES
('03/01/2023'),
('03/05/2023'),
('03/06/2023'),
('03/04/2023'),
('03/07/2023');

INSERT INTO enrollment (SchoolId) VALUES
('tafesa87678645'),
('tafesa87678645'),
('tafesa87678645'),
('tafesa87678645'),
('tafesa87678645');
```

I've tried disabling strict mode, but that hasn't resolved the issue. any help appreciated

Comment: I'm not clear what you are asking, you have defined date as not null so you must provide a valid date when inputting..

Comment: Please update your question with the INSERT statement you are using. Also, just as an FYI, using reserved words such as “date” as column names is a not a good practice

Comment: Why are you inserting into only a single column at a time? This will insert a new row for each value so, for those inserts not into the date column, the date column will be null and therefore error

Comment: @NickW apologies, I'm brand new to this and self taught. can you show me the syntactically correct way to insert multiple data entries under one column of the table without doing it one at a time?

Comment: Hi - you probably need to take a beginners SQL course. There are plenty of free ones on the internet plus on sites like Udemy. Just make sure you pick one that teaches ANSI SQL join syntax (from table A join table B) rather than the old Oracle syntax (from table a, b where a.id = b.id) as that is 30 years out of date - but people still seem to be taught it!

Comment: Records are not inserted column-wise, but as rows, so as one row `INSERT` example, based on your data could look like: `INSERT INTO enrollment (EnrollmentId, \`Date\`, SchoolID) VALUES ('pegsue5687', '03/01/2023', 'tafesa87678645'), (/* same for row 2*/), (/* etc for other rows */);` ... but know that your date format example is NOT how dates are stored, so look for examples. If you add a default to this field to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, then this field will automatically be set by the DB, and not need to be included in the insert.

Comment: @PaulT cheers for the advice, that should fix the snag in my progress, and set me up fine the rest of the project.